# Iterate over array which name is in another variable in bash

Tags: bash, variable, array

I want to iterate over an array which name is in another variable. This is what I tried so far:

```
NTASKSLIST=(384 768 1536 3072)

# there are potentially more arrays like these, each custom defined for every entry in NTASKSLIST
OV384LIST=("16 16 12" "16 16 16" "18 18 12" "18 18 16" "18 18 18")
OV768LIST=("24 16 16" "24 18 18" "32 18 18" "36 18 18" "36 24 24")

for NTASKS in "${NTASKSLIST[@]}"
do

  OVLIST="OV${NTASK}LIST"
  # OVLIST now holds the name of the array I want to iterate

  # now I want to iterate over the array which name is in OVLIST but it does not work
  for OV in "${!OVLIST[@]}"
  do
    echo $OV # prints "0" because OVLIST has only 1 item (the name of the array I want to iterate)

    # here I want to do stuff with OV and NTASKS

  done
done
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do this? Alternative approaches which accomplish the same thing should to as well.

**Edit:**

As shown the comments by [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) the answer to my question is:

```
    OVNAME="OV${NTASKS}LIST"[@]
    OVLIST=( "${!OVNAME}" )

    for OV in "${OVLIST[@]}"
```

Comment: so, in your case the answer there translates to (why do you use caps?): `for ntask in "${ntaskslist[@]}"; do ovlist="ov${ntask}list"[@]; new=( "${!ovlist}" ); for element in "${new[@]}"; do printf %s\\n "$element";done; done`

Comment: I used caps because I thought that this is convention in Unix, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization told me something different. But it shouldn't make any difference, should it?

Comment: Sry, my fault. I updated my post.